# Definition of Vassiliev invariants for framed oriented knots

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

In Bar-Natan's paper "On the Vassiliev Knot Invariants", he says that it is not difficult to extend the definition of Vassiliev invariants for (unframed) knots to framed knots, but I don't know how to extend it.

If we define it in the most obvious way, then I think we can't assure that every ($F$-valued) Vassiliev invariant (of degree $m$) gives a $F$-valued function on chord diagrams (of degree $m$). It is because that when $K$ is a framed singular knot of degree $m+1$ and $K_+$(resp. $K_-$) is its positive (resp. negative) desingularization with respect to one singular point, then the framing of $K_+$ is twisted two more than the framing of $K_-$.

A possible modification of the definition I came up with is to change the way of extending framed knot invariant $V$ to framed singular knots. Specifically, instead of using $V(K)=V(K_+)-V(K_-)$, we use $V(K)=V(K_+)-V(K_-')$ where $K_-'$ is a framed singular knot whose underlying singular knot is the same as $K_-$ and whose framing is one more than the framing of $K_-$. However this modification fails because $F$-valued functions on chord diagrams coming from "framed Vassiliev invariants" may not be weight systems (i.e. may not satisfy $4T^*$-relation).

So how should we define Vassiliev invariants for framed oriented knots?

Comment: I think the first interpretation, where framing changes by 2, is correct. A way to work with framed knots is through knot diagrams, where writhe is the framing, and you use the ["regular isotopy" Reidemeister moves](https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/chp%3A10.1007%2F978-3-030-05213-3_3/MediaObjects/459320_1_En_3_Figh_HTML.png), where the first move is replaced by one where two opposite loops cancel (preserving writhe). Chord diagrams should work the same as before, though weight systems drop framing independence.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I used the word "chord diagram" as an oriented circle with finite disjoint chords (i.e. finite disjoint pairs of distinct points on the circle). I understood that you say the first interpretation is correct if we use "framed" chord diagrams. Is it right?

Comment: I'm saying that you use chord diagrams like usual, but you just make sure to work with framed knot diagrams (you can change framings by $\pm 1$ by applying the Reidemeister I move, using the blackboard framing convention).  Chmutov's Introduction to Vassiliev Invariants discusses this.

Comment: I see. But I worry about that, in framed case, some Vassiliev invariants may not give a "well-defined" function on chord diagrams because crossing-change changes framings by ±2. In unframed case, to show that every Vassiliev invariant (of degree m) gives a well-defined function on chord diagrams (of degree m), we use the fact that if two singular knots gives the same chord diagram, they are related by 
 crossing changes. However, in framed case, I think this fact does not hold because crossing-change changes framings by ±2 not ±1.

Comment: I had thought there was a way to prove that the framing doesn't matter for knots with $m$ singularities using knots with $\geq m+1$ singularities, but I'm not so sure anymore. What Chmutov and Yetter talk about in their books is considering singularities in the framing itself, and this gives the needed additional axiom that for framed knots with $m$ singularities you can change the framing arbitrarily.  (Without this axiom, I guess you might have to make do with having "even" and "odd" chord diagrams!)

Comment: It certainly seems like it would work that way. Thank you very much for your thoughtful answer.